# Загрузка файла на удаленный сервер без использования формы

Tags: php, curl, fileupload

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос - как загрузить/передать файл(в качестве указателя на него используя URL-на моем сервере), на другой удаленный сервер. Ниже приведен код загрузки изображения на хостинг картинок с использованием формы input file. Работает замечетельно.
Но проблема начинается, когда пробую заменить

```
$filename = $img['tmp_name'];
```

на

```
$filename = $image_pass; // где $image_pass == путь к файлу на 
сервере-доноре (типа http://server.com/images/image.jpg)
```

После 5 часов гугления, появляется понимание, что в $_FILES(при использовании формы загрузки файла) - формируется некая структура

```
$_FILES == Array ( 
[name] => 1.jpg 
[type] => image / jpeg 
[tmp_name] => http://server.com/images/image.jpg
[error] => 0 [size] => 60541 
)
```

загружаемый файл - сохраняется во внутренностях массива $_FILES, потом частями пересылается методом POST на удаленный сервер.

**Как имитировать работу формы, но отправлять обработчику только лишь URL-файлов а не кодированное значение с массива $_FILES?

Помогите пожалуйста, кто-чем сможет!**

Рабочий код ниже:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Upload Using Imgur API</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" style="margin-top:10px;height:100%;">
    <h1>Image Upload Using Imgur API</h1>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        Choose Image : <input name="img" size="35" type="file"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <?
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $img = $_FILES['img'];
        if ($img['name'] == '') {
            echo "<h2>An Image Please.</h2>";
        } else {
            $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
            $client_id = "77777777777777777";//Your Client ID here
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
            $timeout = 30;
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $pms = json_decode($out, true);
            $url = $pms['data']['link'];
            if ($url != "") {
                echo "<h2>Uploaded Without Any Problem</h2>";
                echo "<img src='$url'/>";
                echo $url;
            } else {
                echo "<h2>There's a Problem</h2>";
                echo $pms['data']['error']['message'];
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Тэг `PDO` лишний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя переслать фаил урлом. Вам нужно прочитать данные из фаилы и переслать их.

Проблема возникает из-за того что функция `fopen` ожидает путь до локального файла а не url.

Когда вы загружаете фаил через форму, он сначала сохраняется на сервере во временной папке. `tmp_name` указывает на этот временный фаил, а не url.
Обычно там что,то типа `/tmp/some_random_letters`.

Если сделаете `$filename = "./images/image.jpg";` должно начать работать (предполагаю что php фаил находится в корне (т.е. доаступен по адресу `http://server.com/<image_upload.php>`)).

Answer (score 1):

Если есть url до файла доступный серверу то можно так

```
$fileName = explode('/',$url);
$fileName = $fileName[count($fileName)-1];
$result = file_put_contents($fileName,file_get_contents($url));
if($result) {
     echo 'OK';
} else {
     echo 'fail';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно пересылать файл урлом, то логично предположить, что на сервере нужно будет его по этому урлу прочитать :)

Только учтите, ссылки на картинки должны быть полными, т.е. например `http://site.ru/images/image.jpg`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Upload Using Imgur API</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" style="margin-top:10px;height:100%;">
    <h1>Image Upload Using Imgur API</h1>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        Choose Image : <input name="img" size="35" type="text"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <?
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $img = $_POST['img'];
        if ($img == '') {
            echo "<h2>An Image Please.</h2>";
        } else {
            $client_id = "77777777777777777";//Your Client ID here
            $data = file_get_contents($img);
            $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
            $timeout = 30;
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $pms = json_decode($out, true);
            $url = $pms['data']['link'];
            if ($url != "") {
                echo "<h2>Uploaded Without Any Problem</h2>";
                echo "<img src='$url'/>";
                echo $url;
            } else {
                echo "<h2>There's a Problem</h2>";
                echo $pms['data']['error']['message'];
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```